# Writing Xtext Grammar for method calls like java

Tags: xtext

Hi  I have already written grammar like below for one of my requirement which uses xtext editor.

```
Feature:
    dclass=[ecore::EClass] (".")? (feature=[ecore::EStructuralFeature])?;
```

Basically i'm crossreferencing my emf model, so that i can call methods on my Objects, Which supports functionality like below-  If I have Employee class with methods getSalary() And Salary as class with method getBasic()
Presently below call is supported

```
Employee.salary
```

But what i want is since the above code returns Salary i want to call further methods on that

```
Employee.salary.amount

or Employee.getSalary().getAmount()
```

How can i achieve that? Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just changed the grammar as below and then through scope provider i achieved the content assist.

```
Feature:
    {Feature} dclass=[ecore::EClass];

DotExpression:
    (Feature) ({DotExpression.ref=current} "."tail=[ecore::EStructuralFeature])*;
```

Use DotExpression to get the java like behaviour